# JAVA ArrayList cant find element via indexOf()

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

Im writing a short program and I have a problem.

[image: State before fail]

There is a problem with more details.

I have function

```
public CardStck from(Card card)
int pos = this.cardList.indexOf(card);
```

card for this example is Card(value=5, color="D")- as u see on the debugging screen
Even there is that card im searching for 5(D) (diamond 5 card) in this.cardList **the value of pos is -1 (not found)**

Could anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Have you implemented `equals()`?

Comment: You need to override your hashCode and equals method to check your equality so that indexof method would select accordingly

Comment: Did you override `equals/hasCode` method in the `Card` class?

Comment: Have you overwritten `Equals()` in your `Card` class?

Comment: Anyone hear an echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your card class, implement the "equals" method, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object t){
    if(!(t instanceof Card)){
        return false; 
    }
    Card c = (Card)t;
    //Compare however you want, ie
    return (c.getValue() == this.getValue()) & (c.getColor().equals(this.getColor());
}
```

there may be some other null checks or safety stuff you want to include, like making sure color isn't null etc, but that's the general idea.

Comment: It works, thank you so much!

Comment: `equals()` shouldn't throw an exception when the object is of another type.

Comment: I was providing the general solution. If he wants to do type checking etc. he can. No need to down vote. I stated explicitly that it wasn't a complete example.

Comment: I don't mind that it's incomplete, I mind that it's wrong. Type checking isn't optional; you must check `t instanceof Card` before trying to cast (after which you don't need the null check btw).

Comment: @shmosel satisfactory? if not, feel free to make an edit.